# Как отловить исключение в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть ошибка:

```
WARNING:aiogram:Goodbye!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/zahar/Downloads/bot/bot.py", line 21, in
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
File "C:\Users\zahar\Downloads\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\executor.py", line 41, in start_polling
executor.start_polling(reset_webhook=reset_webhook, timeout=timeout, relax=relax, fast=fast)
File "C:\Users\zahar\Downloads\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\executor.py", line 305, in start_polling
loop.run_until_complete(self._startup_polling())
File "C:\Users\zahar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
File "C:\Users\zahar\Downloads\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\executor.py", line 356, in _startup_polling
await self._welcome()
File "C:\Users\zahar\Downloads\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\executor.py", line 346, in _welcome
user = await self.dispatcher.bot.me
File "C:\Users\zahar\Downloads\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 27, in me
setattr(self, '_me', await self.get_me())
File "C:\Users\zahar\Downloads\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 176, in get_me
result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_ME, payload)
File "C:\Users\zahar\Downloads\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 201, in request
return await api.make_request(self.session, self.__token, method, data, files,
File "C:\Users\zahar\Downloads\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 104, in make_request
return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
File "C:\Users\zahar\Downloads\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 84, in check_result
exceptions.Unauthorized.detect(description)
File "C:\Users\zahar\Downloads\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 137, in detect
raise cls(description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.Unauthorized: Unauthorized
```

Я хотел бы сделать так, чтобы когда возникала эта ошибка, код автоматически полностью останавливался при помощи `os._exit(0)`, но я не знаю как отловить это исключение или ошибку.

Если написать код, который внизу, то ничего не произойдёт и бот будет дальше работать с этой ошибкой:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        executor.start_polling(dp)
    except Exception:
        os._exit(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```python
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
try:
    executor.start_polling(dp)
except:
    os._exit(0)
```

Этот код сработает при вызове любой из ошибок в процессе работы программы, как вариант, после except указать текст конкретно Вашей ошибки

```python
except: aiogram.utils.exceptions.Unauthorized
```

Comment: можете дать более развернутый ответ?

Comment: Этот код выполняется при появлении любой ошибки. Вы точно импортировали модуль os?

Comment: Да, не мне. Просто добавьте пояснение к вашему коду в сам ответ. Что поменялось для ТС и почему ваш код сработает в отличии от того, что описано в вопросе. [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1297185/edit)

Comment: Пояснил в ответе. У автора данного вопроса после except идет Exception, которое и обозначает только ошибки Exception, если же ничего не указывать, то при любой ошибке, будет работать данный блок кода

Comment: os._exit(0) не выполняется, по прежнему выводится ошибка `except: aiogram.utils.exceptions.Unauthorized`, поясню более подробно, мне необходимо, чтобы во время работы бота и после его удаления в bot father весь код немедленно прекращал свою работу

Comment: У тебя идет polling, это цикл, соответственно, вызывать try, exept в таком случае бессмысленно, как вариант переписать модуль exceptions ов в aiogram, сейчас попробую

Comment: @MaximChyorny https://youtu.be/l2_tH6tgQ08

Comment: @Batman22827 ты просто незаменим! ❤